# Can't run parse anypic on my Xcode 5.1

Tags: objective-c, xcode, parse-platform

I tried to run parse anypic on my Xcode 5.1 however, I failed within the errors that occurred on this part of the source.

The name of the file is `PAPActivityFeedViewController` and the problematic part of the source is as follows:

```
if (self.objects.count == 0 || ![[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate performSelector:@selector(isParseReachable)])
```

it saids, `undeclared selector`...

P.S. does anyone knows any tutorials how to compile and run anypic on a latest version of Xcode?? 
any respond will be welcomed.

Comment: plus, Xcode keep tells me that anypic source cannot be shown as a code.....

Comment: see github: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Anypic/issues/27 - google is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

```
AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
SEL aSelector = @selector(isParseReachable);
[delegate performSelector:aSelector];
```

Try this, may be it can help.. assuming that isParseReachable is written on appdelegate.